# Solving ODE $y''+y'+2y=\tan(t) $ by laplace transform

Tags: integration

If $y''+y'+2y=\tan(t) $
how can I solve this problem by Laplace?

There are some functions have not Laplace transform.
Is the tan function on of them?
And if it is one of them, how I can solve it?

Comment: What have you tried ? Where are you stuck ? Just apply linearity of Laplace transform and use the fact that $\mathcal L\{f'\}(p)=p\mathcal L\{f\}-f(0).$

Comment: @surb: "just apply": try it first...

Comment: Are you asked to solve by Laplace, or is that your own choice ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: You probably can't obtain a nice closed form, but you can at least easily obtain a formal solution $y$ (that will involve $\mathcal L$ and $\mathcal L^{-1}$).

Comment: @Surb: this is not what you expect when solving by Laplace. You expect an explicit analytical solution.

Comment: Note that $\tan t$ has poles on the real line, so its Laplace transform is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Let's subistute $y(t) =u(t)e^{\lambda t}$, where $\lambda$ i some yet unspecified constant. We get
$$ y' = (u'+\lambda u)e^{\lambda t}$$
$$ y'' = (u''+2\lambda u' + \lambda^2 u)e^{\lambda t}$$
So the equation takes form
$$ \big(u''+(2\lambda +1)u' + (\lambda^2 + \lambda +2) u\big)e^{\lambda t} = \tan t$$
If we now choose $\lambda$ such that $\lambda^2+\lambda+2=0$ (that is $\lambda=\frac{-1\pm i\sqrt{7}}{2}$) the equation becomes
$$ \big(u''+(2\lambda +1)u' \big)e^{\lambda t} = \tan t$$
$$ u''+(2\lambda +1)u'  = e^{-\lambda t}\tan t$$
$$ e^{-(2\lambda +1)t}\big(e^{(2\lambda +1)t}u'\big)'  = e^{-\lambda t}\tan t$$
$$ \big(e^{(2\lambda +1)t}u'\big)'  = e^{(\lambda +1) t}\tan t$$
$$ e^{(2\lambda +1)t}u'  = \int e^{(\lambda +1) t}\tan t\, dt$$
$$ u' =e^{-(2\lambda +1)t}  \int e^{(\lambda +1) t}\tan t\, dt$$
$$ u = \int e^{-(2\lambda +1)t}  \left(\int e^{(\lambda +1) t}\tan t\, dt\right) dt$$
$$ y = e^{\lambda t}\int e^{-(2\lambda +1)t}  \left(\int e^{(\lambda +1) t}\tan t\, dt\right) dt$$

Answer (score 0):

Wolfram Alpha finds a hair-raising solution to the ODE that involves the hypergeometric function with complex arguments.

I doubt that a human being can achieve that by hand in less than a day, and even less using the Laplace transform.

Comment: Bad downvote. Please explain.

Comment: There are many haters in all the word aahhah....:-) +1.